# Создать программу c#

Tags: c#

Напишите программу в с#, которая получает три числа и выводит количество одинаковых чисел в этой цепочке.

Пример 1:

```
Введите три числа:
1 1 1
Все числа одинаковые.
```

Пример 2:

```
Введите три числа:
1 2 1
Два числа одинаковые.
```

Пример 3:

```
Введите три числа:
1 2 3
Нет одинаковых чисел.
```

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int a, b, c;
    a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
    b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
    c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

    if (a == b && c == a)
      Console.WriteLine(2);
    else if (a == b)
      { Console.WriteLine(3); }
    else if (b == c)
      { Console.WriteLine(2); }
    else if (a == c)
      { Console.WriteLine(3); }
    else
      Console.WriteLine(0);

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: тут помогают что-то сделать или понять, а не делают вместо Вас. Даже если ли вы совсем не знаете как это сделать вы должны приложить код или описание ваших попыток решения задачи

Comment: @shad, кнопка "править" же есть - добавь код в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
> ```

`Console.Read()` читает не слово, а символ. Ты код этого символа перегоняешь из числа в число - дело бесполезное.

Читай всю строку и сплить её на слова:

```
var arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

можно сразу превратить в числа с помощью `int.Parse`.

А дальше советую продолжать работать с массивом, а не с 3 переменными.

https://ideone.com/GwngUv

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Console.WriteLine
    (
      Console.ReadLine()
        .Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(int.Parse)
        .Distinct()
        .Count()
    );
  }
}
```

---

Исходный ответ:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(args.Take(3).Select(int.Parse).Distinct().Count());
  }
}
```

Comment: Очень много не понимаю, как превратить в числа и работать с массивом? Хотя-бы 1 часть для примера

Comment: @shad, дополнил.